# Read Access Violation while trying to use variables through shared pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, nullpointerexception, shared-ptr

This is for my university coursework.

I have a class called `timestep` that is going to be used as a typical timer in a game engine to calculate frame times, etc, and an `application` class.

I'm struggling to get my head around shared pointers, but am required to use one to access the `timestep` class from the `application` class. It doesn't throw up errors until the program is running, at which point it prints my `"PRE TIMER"` log to the console, and throws an exception after reaching `timer->setStart()`, flags the line `start = .....` in the `setStart` method, and says `**this** was nullptr`.

Timestep.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <chrono>

namespace Engine {
    class Timestep {
    private:
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start;
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point end; 
    public:
        Timestep();
        void setStart();
        void setEnd();
        float getTimeSeconds() const;
        float GetTimeMilliSeconds() const;
    };
}
```

timestep.cpp:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "engine_pch.h"
#include "core/timestep.h"

namespace Engine {
    Timestep::Timestep(){}

    void Timestep::setStart() {
        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }

    void Timestep::setEnd() {
        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    }

    float Timestep::getTimeSeconds() const {
        std::chrono::duration<float> time = end - start;
        return time.count();
    }

    float Timestep::GetTimeMilliSeconds() const {
        std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli> time = end - start;
        return time.count();
    }

}
```

application.cpp:

```cpp
#include "engine_pch.h"
#include "core/application.h"


namespace Engine {
    Application* Application::s_instance = nullptr;
    std::shared_ptr<Timestep> timer;

    Application::Application()
    {

        if (s_instance == nullptr)
        {
            s_instance = this;
        }
        log::log();
        LOG_INFO("Logger init success");

    }

    Application::~Application()
    {

    }

    void Application::run()
    {
        LOG_INFO("PRE TIMER");
        timer->setStart();
        LOG_INFO("POST TIMER");
        while (s_instance) {
            timer->setEnd();
            float a = timer->getTimeSeconds();
            LOG_INFO("Time since last frame is {0}", a);
            timer->setStart();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your `timer` in application.cpp is not pointing to any instance of `Timestep`, incurring the nullptr error. Explained simply, your shared pointer was not initialized.

Assuming that you want a separate instance of Timestep for each instance of Application, maybe you could solve the issue by initializing your `std::shared_ptr<Timestep> timer;`

Instead of

```
std::shared_ptr<Timestep> timer;
```

Try

```
std::shared_ptr<Timestep> timer(new Timestep());
```

Comment: Thanks for this, such a simple missed piece of code. A small followup question, again, due to ignorance of pointers. If I want to initialise in the application constructor instead of where it is now, what would I need to change?

Comment: Glad it worked :) You could add this line of code in the constructor instead: `timer = make_shared<Timer>();`

this is somewhat like declaring a variable first, and assigning a value later.